# Why is every meromorphic function on the complex projective plane a rational function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

You can use the fact that every holomorphic function on the complex plane with a non essential singularity at $\infty$ is a polynomial by considering $f(1/z)$ and matching up the taylor series to that and $f$.  This gets you most of the way there but what is the last step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by $(z-a_i)^{k_i}$ where $a_1,...,a_n$ are the poles of order $k_1,...,k_n$. Note that not having an essential singularity at $\infty$ and being non-constant means that $f(z) = \infty$ only finitely many times (you can use identity theorem on Riemann surfaces).

This is holomorphic, so you can use the result you mentioned.